# html - Align text next to other div element

Tags: html, css

So I am in quite a peculiar situation. I am trying to make a header that includes my website icon in the top left corner, and a Navigation div element under that(Img is overlaying the Nav element). What I want is the text in the Nav element align next to the picture overlaying it at the left side. 

Here is a picture of my situation (Apparently dont have enough rep to post img):


http://i.imgur.com/qkVwwiw.png


Here is the CSS for the NAV:

```
.nav {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    height:70px;
    width:100%;   
    text-align:left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 0;
}
```

The Corner IMG:

```
div.cornerimg {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 70px;
}
div.cornerimg img {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    margin: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 151px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 151px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 151px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 151px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 151px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 151px;
}
```

And of course the HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
  <a href="home.htm"> Home |</a>
  <a href="download.htm">  Download |</a>
  <a href="suggestions.htm"> Suggestions |</a>
  <a href="https://sites.google.com/site/xeondosbatch/" target="_blank"> Google Site |</a>
</div>

<div class="cornerimg">
  <a href="home.htm">
    <img src="C:\Users\(User)\Desktop\Webpage\homeimg.png" alt="XeonDOS" width="250"             height="230">
  </a>
</div>
```

So hopefully you can see the text behind the img, but I want to try and align the text next to the "XeonDOS" image overlapping the text.


Just tell me some ways to center text next to a div element, that would be great!

Comment: Can you please post the HTML and the CSS?

Comment: Alright, i'll edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a slight change to your HTML structure. I wrapped your menu-links with `<div id="navcontainer"></div>` and gave a `margin-left` of `347px` to it.

```css
div.cornerimg {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 70px;
}
div.cornerimg img {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    margin: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 151px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 151px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 151px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 151px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 151px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 151px;
}
.nav {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    height:70px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 0;
}
div#navcontainer {
    margin-left: 347px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <div id="navcontainer"><a href="home.htm"> Home |</a>
 <a href="download.htm">  Download |</a>
 <a href="suggestions.htm"> Suggestions |</a>
 <a href="https://sites.google.com/site/xeondosbatch/" target="_blank"> Google Site |</a>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="cornerimg"> <a href="home.htm">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="XeonDOS" width="250"             height="230">
  </a>

</div>
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sfexvhf7/5/)**.

Comment: Hey Thanks, I was kind of confused with this topic. I will try and look into the code and understand as much of it as I can, but once again thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the essence of what you need to do:

HTML:

```
<div id='wrapping-div'>
    <div id='image-div'></div>
    <div id='nav-div'></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapping-div {
    display: inline-block;        
}
```

Comment: I have put the code in the post and it does not seem that this works (Unfortunately). It seems to put the overlay out of whack, and the Nav element goes on top. And I was also acctually trying to put the text in the nav element next to the IMG.

Answer (score 0):

left 280px with the .nav

```
left: 280px;
```

Comment: Yes, that is with the nav. But I am trying to make the text in the NAV element be next to the IMG element.

Comment: `padding-left:280px;`